# Variable with placeholder

Tags: 7

I am implementing a couple of **translatable variables** that are exposed via `hook_variable_info()`.

Can I use placeholders in these variables, and process them to replace with the actual values?

As an example: I have a variable that holds the following informational text that will be shown on a page that has a registration form below.

> Please signup here to gain access to the restricted area for @yourcompany

I have been googling around for this, but cannot seem to find any good leads on how to do this (if at all possible?)

Comment: Do you mean the variable is used to save the value for replacing the token `@yourcompany`?

Comment: Jimmy, the variable is used to store the entire message "please sign up...", INCLUDING the @yourcompany token

Comment: How about just use `$message = variable_get_value('variable_name'); $message = format_string('@yourcompany' => $companyname)?`

Comment: Hi Jimmy, I was using tokens right now.
But this is a little more tedious, since i have to create the tokens in advance; Your approach is better since this will allow me to insert the placeholders dynamically! Feel free to add this as the answer so i can tag it.

Comment: I posted in answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is using [format_string](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/format_string/7.x)(), you can have 3 kind of replacement token for different sanitisation and formatting.

> **@variable**: Escaped to HTML using check_plain(). Use this as the default choice for anything displayed on a page on the site.
>
> **%variable**: Escaped to HTML and formatted using drupal_placeholder(), which makes it display as *emphasized* text.
>
> **!variable**: Inserted as is, with no sanitization or formatting. Only use this for text that has already been prepared for HTML display (for example, user-supplied text that has already been run through check_plain() previously, or is expected to contain some limited HTML tags and has already been run through filter_xss() previously).

Example code:

```php
$message = variable_get_value('variable_name');
$message = format_string($message, array('@yourcompany' => $company_name));
```